# How to correctly update the last Fragment from ViewPager when tab is clicked?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Issue description:

1. I have a ViewPager with four Fragments on it;
2. The first and last ones have a RecyclerView on them;
3. When I scroll the ViewPager, everything works fine - which means, all content is loaded as expected;
4. If I click on the last / first tabs (which contains the RecyclerViews and are separeted by three fragments from each other) the RecyclerView content is not displayed on the screen - all other UI components, such as FloatingActionButtons, are;

*I've looked around but all other questions related to this subject seemed to address the problem for scrolling only, and I wasn't able to find anything related to clicking on the tab specifically.*

**PS.: Code is written in Kotlin**

### CODE

Called from an Activity in order to encapsulate the code related to the tab manager:

```
class TabManager {

companion object {
    val INVALID_POSITION_LABEL = "Invalid Position"
}

private var mActivity: AppCompatActivity? = null
private var mViewPagerTab: SmartTabLayout? = null
private var mViewPager: ViewPager? = null

// PUBLIC INTERFACE ============================================================================
fun initViewPager(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
    mActivity = activity

    mViewPager = activity.findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as ViewPager
    mViewPagerTab = activity.findViewById(R.id.tabs) as SmartTabLayout

    mViewPager!!.adapter = AdapterTab(activity.supportFragmentManager)
    mViewPager!!.currentItem = 0

    mViewPagerTab!!.setCustomTabView(setCustomTabView())
    mViewPagerTab!!.setViewPager(mViewPager)
}

fun setViewPagerListener(onChangeListener: (position: Int) -> Unit) {
    mViewPager!!.onPageChangeListener {
        onPageScrolled {
            position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels ->
            onChangeListener(position)
        }
    }
}


// =============================================================================================
private fun setCustomTabView(): SmartTabLayout.TabProvider {
    return SmartTabLayout.TabProvider {
        container,
        position,
        adapter ->
        val icon = mActivity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rsc_homepage_tab_icon, container, false) as ImageView
        when (position) {
            0 -> icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity!!, R.drawable.ic_profile_white_24))
            1 -> icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity!!, R.drawable.ic_magnify_white_24))
            2 -> icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity!!, R.drawable.ic_msg_reply_text_white_24))
            3 -> icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity!!, R.drawable.ic_game_white_24))
            else -> throw IllegalStateException(INVALID_POSITION_LABEL + position)
        }
        icon
    }
}
```

}

PageAdapter for ViewPager items:

```
class AdapterTab(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    private val FRAGMENT_PROFILE = FragmentProfile()
    private val FRAGMENT_SEARCH_USER = FragmentSearchUsers()
    private val FRAGMENT_CHATS = FragmentChats()
    private val FRAGMENT_GAMES = FragmentGames()

    // LIFECYCLE ===================================================================================d
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return "PROFILE"
            1 -> return "SEARCH USER"
            2 -> return "CHATS"
            3 -> return "GAMES"
            else -> return "UNKNOWN"
        }
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 4
    }

    override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
        return POSITION_NONE
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return FRAGMENT_PROFILE
            1 -> return FRAGMENT_SEARCH_USER
            2 -> return FRAGMENT_CHATS
            3 -> return FRAGMENT_GAMES
            else -> return FRAGMENT_GAMES
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problems wasn't about ViewPagers at all. I had 4 Fragments and 3 of them had the a RecyclerView with the same name. This caused a conflict when moving between the pages too fast (first Fragment was destroyed, the RecyclerView elements also destroyed. When that happened, it empts the last Fragment RecyclerView as well).

## SOLUTION

Changed the RecyclerView names to unique names and problem is gonne